# Jackson annotations ignored after deployment to JBOSS

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jackson

I have a class which uses two Jackson annotations:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyObject{

    @JsonProperty(value = "fooVal")
    private String foo;

    public MyObject(){}        

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

When I use the `ObjectMapper` to map the recieved JSON to `MyObject` on a local enviroment in a test case it works without problems, however if I deploy the module to my JBOSS AS all the annotations are being ignored and I can't figure out why.

My `pom.xml` has the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So the library is imported into the WAR folder in deployments.

Why are the annotations ignored after deployment please?

Comment: Library conflicts perhaps - if you are using JBoss 7 it already has (an older version of) Jackson as part of RestEasy.

Comment: @Gimby I've tried redeploying the war without the libs and the behavior didn't change unfortunately..

Comment: @Gimbly actually I had to exclude it in the jboss-deployment-structure.. Thanks a lot for pointing me the right way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in library conflicts due to autoimporting of an older version of Jackson.
The solution was to include:

```
<exclusions>
        <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
        <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
</exclusions>
```

Into `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in the deployment tag.

**Important tip for other developers:**
When using a new library take into consideration your application server's firstclass/lastclass(classloading order preference) setting: [WebSphere](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/urun_rclassloader_inst.html), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), [JBOSS](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/class-loader-howto.html)